# Continuity of $x^n$ in topological sense

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

I want to verify continuity of the functions

$$f:(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{O}[a,b))\to(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{O}(a,b)),\quad x\mapsto x^n,\quad n\in\mathbb{N},$$

where $\mathcal{O}[a,b)$ and $\mathcal{O}(a,b)$ are the topologies generated by half open sets $[a,b)$ and open sets $(a,b)$.

Starting with the case $n\in2\mathbb{N}$ (so $n:=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$), I calculated

\begin{align*}
 f^{-1}((a,b))&=\{x\mid x^{2k}\in(a,b)\} \\ &=(-\sqrt[2k]{b},-\sqrt[2k]{a})\cup(\sqrt[2k]{a},\sqrt[2k]{b}),
\end{align*}
which is an union of open intervals. For an open interval $(a,b)$ we can write

\begin{equation}
 (a,b)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[a+\frac{1}{n},b),
\end{equation}

so we get $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is open in $\mathcal{O}[a,b)$.

For $n\in2\mathbb{N}+1$ (so $n:=2k+1$) I get
\begin{align*}
 f^{-1}((a,b))&=\{x\mid x^{2k+1}\in(a,b)\} \\ &=(\sqrt[2k+1]{a},\sqrt[2k+1]{b}),
\end{align*}
which is again open in $\mathcal{O}[a,b)$ by the same argument as before.

Are my calculations correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For functions from the lower limit topology to the lower limit topology;
Show the identity function is continuous.
Show if f and g are continuous, then f×g is continuous.
Conclude by induction that x$^n$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

$f:\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{O}(a,b)}\to\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{O}(a,b)}$, $f(x)=x^n$ is cont. by iterating $\mathrm{id}:\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{O}(a,b)}\to\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{O}(a,b)}$. Then, by [Prove that if $\tau_2$ is finer than $\tau_1$, then $f: (X,\tau_2) \rightarrow (Y,\sigma_1)$ is continuous.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2879226/prove-that-if-tau-2-is-finer-than-tau-1-then-f-x-tau-2-rightarrow?rq=1) and $\mathcal{O}[a,b)\supseteq\mathcal{O}(a,b)$ you get continuity for $f:\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{O}[a,b)}\to\mathbb{R}_{\mathcal{O}(a,b)}$